# Set DisplayPropertyName value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, t4

I would like to know if there is a maneer (may be with data annotation) to set the value of

> property.DisplayPropertyName

.

Do you have any idea please?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite easy to do:

```
[DisplayName("RenamedProperty")]
```

you can even add a description

```
[Description("Demonstrates DisplayNameAttribute.")]
```

or perhaps you would like it to reference your resources so it adapts itself to the selected language:

```
[Display(Name = "Description", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think you mean to ask how you can choose a *different* property as the display property (i.e., the property that is used to briefly denote objects of your class in the UI).

The Entity Framework Service that generates the metadata for scaffolding choose the first property of string type (as far as I know), but you can change that by applying the `DisplayColumn` attribute to your class:

```
[DisplayColumn("Alias")]
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
}
```

Note, however, that this only works for properties that are actually mapped to a column in the database. (I was trying to use a computed property, not mapped, but that led to an error message while scaffolding.)